# Questions about finding local instructors/communities

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to ask the community, roughly, if anyone knows of Theravadan Buddhist teachers in the Fort Collins, Colorado area, if they know of lists of communities that I could reference to find this information, or if they know the best place to ask.

Is that an appropriate question?

Answer (score 3):

It's very very localized to a specific place and time (where: Ft. Collins, when: now), so I'd view it as not a great fit for a SE site. Basically the questions that make great fits are those that are likely to help future visitors in some way, shape, or form.

That said, it's a great question to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism).

Answer (score 0):

I had success with http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/ when looking for local communities. In fact, this is how I found my Zen Master.

Oh but your question is, whether that's an appropriate question. I would say if you phrase it "Is there an online directory of local Buddhist communities?" instead of specifically for Fort Collins, then yes, it is a good question. Go ahead and ask it ;)

Comment: I suppose the downvote means my answer is not useful? :)

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). :)

Comment: Oh it means someone disagreed that such answers are appropriate. Now I get it.

Comment: Yup! You're in the clear.